# Impossible remove Logical Volumes or Volume Group LVM2

Tags: lvm, partition

After a disk crash part of a LVM group, I can't use LVM2 properly.

If like delete a Logical Volume impossible (Error on SATA Volumen)

```
lvscan
Couldn't find device with uuid vxHO8W-FPbL-9d5N-GUVb-Lo8d-D9WZ-1RY3Bx.
inactive          '/dev/sata/isos' [100.00 GiB] inherit
inactive          '/dev/sata/vm-999-disk-1' [10.00 GiB] inherit
inactive          '/dev/sata/vm-300-disk-1' [51.00 GiB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/pve/vm-103-disk-1' [200.00 GiB] inherit

lvremove /dev/sata/isos
Couldn't find device with uuid vxHO8W-FPbL-9d5N-GUVb-Lo8d-D9WZ-1RY3Bx.
Segmentation fault

dmsetup remove --force sata
device-mapper: table ioctl on sata failed: No such device or address
device-mapper: reload ioctl on sata failed: No such device or address
device-mapper: remove ioctl on sata failed: No such device or address
Command failed
```

Try also, vgreduce --removemissing, and other commands for delete ALL on SATA Volumen and start form 0.

PVE volumen it's on production.

Apreciate help

Answer (score 3):

Start over, initialize the disks again with new LVM VGs and restore from backup.

Comment: I don't like restore anything. Only like DESTROY "sata" VOlumen. I can't initialize disk, i can't modify anything... all "lvremove /dev/sata/isos
  Couldn't find device with uuid vxHO8W-FPbL-9d5N-GUVb-Lo8d-D9WZ-1RY3Bx.
Segmentation fault" If you can explain more extended...

Comment: It doesn't matter what you like, it's highly likely the LVM structure is damaged beyond repair. From what you appear to know, it's also likely you aren't able to recover from this on your own and I would suggest to get outside help to help you with this. [SF] isn't the place to get this help though, the back and forth necessary just doesn't work here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after several hours of try, get a solution.

```
 pvcreate --uid "mising_uid_old_disk" --retorefile /etc/lvm/archive/<latets__file_with_correct_data>.vg /dev/<partition_of_new_disk_replace_old_disk"
```

After this action, you must remove all LV with problem (lost data on old disk)